# Do cameras turn off their sensors when entering the menu?

Tags: equipment-damage, noise, heat

Let me clarify this: **In movie mode** (or live view), the sensor is gathering light all the time, and due to this the heat starts to build up.

This is a problem in certain situations, due to the heat produces more noise and sometimes the heat is so intense that the camera turn off itself for security reasons.

I've heard a rumor that if you enter the menu while in movie mode, the sensor gets "deactivated", reducing the heat on it. This is very convenient due to switching from live view to the normal mode back and forth has some impact in the shutter.

**Is this true? How do you prevent heat without leaving the live view?**

Comment: By "has some inpact in the shutter", do you mean that the mirror comes back down, or something else? What are you worried about? (Noise, time, wear, or other?)

Comment: @mattdm The increment in shutter actuations. Al tough entering and leaving LV doesn't increment it (the file number doesn't goes up) it has some impact on the system and probably has the same effect as taking a photo.

Answer (score 1):

As far as going into a menu whilst recording, I can tell you that my Canon T1i does not permit the action. That is, pressing the MENU button results in no action, and recording continues.

Going into MENU is only supported in LIVE VIEW while not recording. Here you may see some heat savings as the return *back* to to LIVE VIEW takes around a half-second to accomplish, so I expect there is some initialization of the sensor going on. That said, the mirror remains up, and the sensor remains exposed during this time. I can't, however, see any reason to be reading the data out while in a menu.

Perhaps your camera supports going into a menu while recording, but I'm thinking that Canon dSLRs, anyway, are out of the equation on that one.

Comment: On my 550D, returning from the menu is instant.

Comment: Even if you could go into the menu while recording, I can't imagine it would effect the sensor at all *since its still recording*.